# Why are spaces not allowed while setting up aliases in .bashrc

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-alias

Coming from the Windows world, I tend to type `cls` to clear the console. I wanted to set up an alias so `cls` would still work.

I read an article online that mentioned you cannot have spaces between the alias name, equal sign, and command. For example,

```
alias cls = 'clear' <---- doesn't work
alias cls='clear'   <---- works
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way it's set up... bash's man page (or `help alias`) shows how spaces have a meaning too:

> alias [-p] [name[=value] ...]
>
> Alias with no arguments or with the -p option prints the list of  aliases  in  the  form
>                 alias  name=value  on standard output.  When arguments are supplied, an alias is defined
>                 for each name whose value is given.  *A trailing **space** in  value causes the next word  to
>                 be  checked  for  alias  substitution  when the alias is expanded.*